# How to seperate stacked bars in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I have two dictionaries which's values are the number of people...

```
d_1={1947: 1, 1950: 1, 1951: 2, 1955: 2, 1956: 1, 1957: 2, 1958: 2, 1959: 3, 1960: 1....}

d_2={1936: 1, 1945: 1, 1948: 2, 1949: 1, 1950: 2, 1951: 2, 1952: 3, 1953: 1, 1954: 41..}
```

And i want to create bar plot that displays the number of people . And the X-axis is formed in year .

When I used this code format is almost the same except the stacked bars. I want them to be seperated.How can I fix that?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()

    x1=[t for t in d_1.keys()]
    y1=[k for k in d_1.values()]
    x2=[m for m in d_2.keys()]
    y2=[n for n in d_2.values()]


    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    index = np.arange(len(years_without_duplicates)) 
    #list which has the years without duplicates

    bar_width = 0.35

    rects1 = plt.bar(x1, y1, bar_width,color='b')
    rects2 = plt.bar(x2, y2, bar_width, color='r')

    plt.xlabel('Years')
    plt.ylabel('number of people')
    plt.xticks([i for i in range(min(years_without_duplicates),max(years_without_duplicates)+1)],rotation=80,fontsize=6)

    plt.legend()



    plt.tight_layout()

    plt.show()
```

[image: my bars are stacked but i want them to be seperated.]

Answer (score 2):

Just shift the bars:

```
bar_width = 0.35
x1 = [t - bar_width / 2 for t in d_1.keys()]
y1 = [k for k in d_1.values()]
x2 = [m + bar_width / 2 for m in d_2.keys()]
y2 = [n for n in d_2.values()]
```

[image]